# Displaying one string from a list of multiple strings

Tags: php, arrays, pdo

I'm trying to grab data from this array, but when I do `var_dump($ArrayedLevels['Attack']);` it returns `NULL`, I know for a fact that it was able to grab the data from the SQL database, I think it has something to do with my array. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
include("highscoresconfig.php");

$GrabXP = $database2->prepare("SELECT * FROM `skills` WHERE `playerName` = ?");
$GrabXP->execute(array($playerName));
$MainResult = $GrabXP->fetchAll();

$ArrayedLevels = $array = [
    "Attack" => $MainResult['Attacklvl'],
    "Defence" => $MainResult['Defencelvl'],
    "Strength" => $MainResult['Strengthlvl'],
    "Hitpoints" => $MainResult['Hitpointslvl'],
    "Ranged" => $MainResult['Rangelvl'],
    "Prayer" => $MainResult['Prayerlvl'],
    "Magic" => $MainResult['Magiclvl'],
    "Cooking" => $MainResult['Cookinglvl'],
    "Woodcutting" => $MainResult['Woodcuttinglvl'],
    "Fletching" => $MainResult['Fletchinglvl'],
    "Fishing" => $MainResult['Fishinglvl'],
    "Firemaking" => $MainResult['Firemakinglvl'],
    "Crafting" => $MainResult['Craftinglvl'],
    "Smithing" => $MainResult['Smithinglvl'],
    "Mining" => $MainResult['Mininglvl'],
    "Herblore" => $MainResult['Herblorelvl'],
    "Agility" => $MainResult['Agilitylvl'],
    "Thieving" => $MainResult['Thievinglvl'],
    "Slayer" => $MainResult['Slayerlvl'],
    "Farming" => $MainResult['Farminglvl'],
    "Runecrafting" => $MainResult['Runecraftlvl'],
    "Hunter" => $MainResult['Hunterlvl'],
    "Construction" => $MainResult['Constructionlvl'],
    "Summoning" => $MainResult['Summoninglvl'],
    "Dungeoneering" => $MainResult['Dungeoneeringlvl'],
];
var_dump($ArrayedLevels["Attack"]);
```

Comment: If you indent code blocks by four spaces (or select in the editor and click the `{}` button, or Ctrl+K), it will be properly formatted.

Comment: Ah alright, thanks Chris.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem might be because the fetchAll() returns all the rows of your query.

```
if($GrabXP->execute(array($playerName))){
    //Success
    $MainResult = $GrabXP->fetchAll();
    /*
    This will give you all the rows. Use a foreach loop to iterate through all the rows.
    If you want only the first row, add this-
    */
    $MainResult = $MainResult[0];
    //The rest of your code.
    $ArrayedLevels = $array = Array(
    "Attack" => $MainResult['Attacklvl'],
        ...
    );
    var_dump($ArrayedLevels["Attack"]);
}
else{
    //Failure
}
```

Comment: Still returns NULL, am I able to get data from an already fetched PDO inside of an array?

Comment: @Patrick check the edit. Perform this, and in each else{} part,echo something so that you will know where the error is happening.

Comment: Failed at the array_key_exists part.

Comment: @Patrick I think i got why it failed. The error was in your fetchAll(). It returns all the rows. So select the first one or use a foreach loop. Check the edit.

Comment: I don't want to be running foreach loops with an array, I chose to do this with an array because the foreach loop was slowing down the speed, I got it from around 11 seconds down to 7-8 second page loading time :/ Thought arrays would be a better alternative. But adding the $MainResult = $MainResult[0]; Worked! But only problem is the format is string(2) "99", and I feel like parsing each one to get rid of it would take lots of extra time.

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand, var_dump($ArrayedLevels["Attack"]) should output "99" and nothing else.

Comment: Yeah it should, but it's outputting NULL.

Comment: Are you using the foreach loop or assigning $MainResult like above? I tried it, and it seems to be working.

Comment: My array looks like     $ArrayedLevels = array(
    "Attack" => $MainResult['Attacklvl']); and I'm dumping it like var_dump($ArrayedLevels["Attack"]);

Comment: Try echoing the $MainResult['Attacklvl']. Do this - 
$MainResult = $GrabXP->fetchAll();
$MainResult = $MainResult[0];
echo $MainResult['Attacklvl'];
$ArrayedLevels = array( "Attack" => $MainResult['Attacklvl']);
var_dump($ArrayedLevels["Attack"]);
This should work.

Comment: Rather then arraying it I'll just call it straight from the fetched data. AKA $MainResult['Attacklvl'];. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The brackets don't work in PHP when creating a new array, use `array()` to create one.

Actually: as of PHP 5.4 they do work, see here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Answer (score 0):

Try `var_dump($MainResult);`

if all good, try create your array like this:

```
$ArrayedLevels = array(
    "Attack" => $MainResult['Attacklvl'],
    "Defence" => $MainResult['Defencelvl'],
    "Strength" => $MainResult['Strengthlvl'],
    "Hitpoints" => $MainResult['Hitpointslvl'],
    "Ranged" => $MainResult['Rangelvl'],
    "Prayer" => $MainResult['Prayerlvl'],
    "Magic" => $MainResult['Magiclvl'],
    "Cooking" => $MainResult['Cookinglvl'],
    "Woodcutting" => $MainResult['Woodcuttinglvl'],
    "Fletching" => $MainResult['Fletchinglvl'],
    "Fishing" => $MainResult['Fishinglvl'],
    "Firemaking" => $MainResult['Firemakinglvl'],
    "Crafting" => $MainResult['Craftinglvl'],
    "Smithing" => $MainResult['Smithinglvl'],
    "Mining" => $MainResult['Mininglvl'],
    "Herblore" => $MainResult['Herblorelvl'],
    "Agility" => $MainResult['Agilitylvl'],
    "Thieving" => $MainResult['Thievinglvl'],
    "Slayer" => $MainResult['Slayerlvl'],
    "Farming" => $MainResult['Farminglvl'],
    "Runecrafting" => $MainResult['Runecraftlvl'],
    "Hunter" => $MainResult['Hunterlvl'],
    "Construction" => $MainResult['Constructionlvl'],
    "Summoning" => $MainResult['Summoninglvl'],
    "Dungeoneering" => $MainResult['Dungeoneeringlvl'],
);
```

Comment: The var_dump($MainResult); worked, I tried changing it to $ArrayedLevels = array(, But it still returned NULL.

Comment: how does the result of your dump look like? is it something like this $MainResult['Attacklvl'] or $MainResult[0]['Attacklvl'] ?

Comment: Here's an example of what the first dumped line looks like (Just showing the attack one) array(1) { [0]=> array(102) { ["playerName"]=> string(7) "patrick" [0]=> string(7) "patrick" ["Attacklvl"]=> string(2) "99"

Comment: it's because your $MainResult is a multilevel array, you need to have something like this "Attack" => $MainResult[1]['Attacklvl']

Comment: I couldn't really see the levelling from the dump result you pasted. can you plz paste at least an indented array at your first index on  gist.github.com

Answer (score 0):

first of all try to print the structure of the variable $MainResult:

```
var_dump($MainResult);
```

FetchAll return an array with all restuls like

```
resutl = [
 [0] => ['first row'],
 [1] => ['sec. row']
]
```

you will See The variable `$MainResult` looks like:

```
MailResult => [
  [0] => ['Attacklvl' => 'foo'],
  [1] => ['Defencelvl' => 'bar'] 
]
```